# compiling c code after linking pro C library generates linker error: undefined reference to function sqlcxt

Tags: gcc, undefined, linker-errors, symbols

In RedHat Linux 5.0 system, when I try to compile C program (the C program has calls to proc functions) with library that contains object files of pro C files, the linker throws error like   "Undefined reference to sqlcxt(void * *,unsigned int *,struct sqlexd *,struct sqlcxp const *)"

I've already tried to link libclntsh.so library and have given the path to the library too, but still I couldn't link successfully.  Help and guidance would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This one was really bad for me (HOURS of searching over 3 days).  Ends up that you need to tell PROC*C that the code is going to be CPP so PRO*C will put the extern "C" on the code itself.

`PCCFLAGS=ireclen=132 oreclen=132 select_error=no DBMS=V8 userid=dwqs999/workque@dev127.uprr.com sqlcheck=full mode=ANSI code=CPP lines=yes cpp_suffix=cpp`